# How to get mobile call history using capacitor in angular v14

Tags: angular, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I need a way to get call history using a capacitor in angular v14
please help

I tried to use Cordova-plugin-catalog and working well to get call history but crashed on some screens so I deleted this library and I can not find any other libraries to do the same.

**Idea of what I want**
I want to build an Android/ios program to work as truecaller application to get some information about the caller from my database